# Evitar zoom dentro de um textarea

Tags: css

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou com o seguinte problema e não soube descrever bem um título, eu tenho um campo que tem um textarea que se adapta a largura da página com 98%.
O que eu quero evitar é que quando o usuário clique dentro dele o textarea de zoom, o que está acontecendo é que quando ele clica para digitar a página fica bem maior e cria a tal barra de scroll horizontal.

- ***Em um dispositivo móvel***

Alguém tem alguma dica ?

Comment: Isto seria em um dispositivo móvel?

Comment: Sim Kazzkiq, está me dando dor de cabeça isso.

Comment: Já tentou adicionar a metatag viewport? Exemplo: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: talves um `max-width` ou um `max-height` resolva isso? para bloquear o scroll horizontal talves `overflow-x: hidden;` Não sei se estas dicas podem resolver o seu problema, mas espero que sim

Comment: Então, quando eu adicionei a viewport o site explodiu e eu não consegui consertar, ela faz as letras se amontuarem uma em sima das outras.

Comment: Acho melhor trocar de estratégia, o aumento é proposital pra facilitar a vida do usuário, bloquear tal recurso é dificultar a vida do usuário e proporcionar uma péssima experiencia.

Comment: Então, eu simulei uma página igual o facebook faz no aplicativo, quando clica no Textarea ele direciona para outra página que tem um textarea com os botões de upload de imagem, imagem do usuário e o textarea toma quase a página toda coloquei uma fonte com 2em para ficar um tamanho bom para o usuário.
Quando fica no focus explode muito o tamanho original.

Answer (score 0):

**Antes de mais** não se esqueca do viewport.. se nao tiver, não precisa de ler mais, tem ai seu problema ;)

No css existe o `:focus` pode usar isso para trabalhar o elemento quando ele está com foco e quando é no mobile

```
@media (min-width:500px){
    textarea:focus{
        ...
    }
}
```

Dessa forma consegue ajustar a altura como quer ;)
Ainda assim seria mais fácil explicar e/ou comprovar o meu raciocínio (não testei, apenas estou tentando ver o seu problema) se deixa-se um pouco do seu código :)

Abraço e boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Um hack bastante usado é setar o tamanho da fonte para `16px`.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
   textarea {
       font-size: 16px;
   }
}
```

Os dispositivos da Apple aplicam zoom nos campos em `focus` até que o texto seja apresentado na tela com o tamanho de `16px`. Setando esse valor desde o início, o zoom não acontece.

Fonte: http://uxcellence.com/2014/01/15/quick-fix-increase-font-size-to-16px-to-fix-input-zoom/

Comment: Pode explicar como isso funciona?